# объявление функции javascript

Tags: javascript, функции

Стажируюсь в компании на фронтенд-разработчика, пришел с строготипизированной джавы, и некоторые моменты мне не очевидны, а именно:

Объявление функции в **js** может быть двух видов:

```
function a(){...}
```

либо

```
var a = function(){...}
```

Вопрос состоит в том, что мне не понятна разница этих объявлений, какие могут быть подводные камни\особенности использования, и каким образом работает второй вариант?(в плане вызова этой функции из переменной, или же различий нет?).

Быть может, влияет на работу GC?

Более предпочтителен развернутый ответ, нечто вроде "это одно и то же" - ответом являться не будет.

Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

В JS функция является значением, таким же как строка или число.
Function Declaration – функция, объявленная в основном потоке кода.
Пример:

```
function a(){...}
```

Function Expression – объявление функции в контексте какого-либо выражения, например присваивания.
Пример:

```
let a = function(){...}
```

Основное отличие между ними: функции, объявленные как Function Declaration, создаются интерпретатором до выполнения кода.

Поэтому их можно вызвать до объявления, например:

```
Hello("World"); // Привет, Вася

function Hello(name) {
  alert( "Hello, " + name );
}
```

А если бы это было объявление Function Expression, то такой вызов бы не сработал:

```
Hello("World"); // ошибка!

let Hello= function(name) {
  alert( "Hello, " + name );
}
```

Это из-за того, что JavaScript перед запуском кода ищет в нём Function Declaration (их легко найти: они не являются частью выражений и начинаются со слова function) и обрабатывает их.

А Function Expression создаются в процессе выполнении выражения, в котором созданы, в данном случае – функция будет создана при операции присваивания `Hello = function...`
В большинстве случаев обычное объявление функции (Function Declaration) – лучше.
Function Expression желательно использовать только там, где это действительно нужно и удобно.

Answer (score 3):

Разница в том, когда можно использовать функцию:

```js
function justForContext() {

  console.log(a);
  console.log(b);

  a();
  try{b();}catch(e){console.log("error calling b");}

  function a() {
    console.log("inside a");
  }
  var b = function() {
    console.log("inside b");
  }

  console.log(b);
  b();

}

justForContext();
```

`а` готово к использованию везде в области видимости, а `b` - после присваивания.

Comment: Еще можно стрелочные функции использовать: var c = ()=>console.log("arrow function");, но это только в ES6 или при использовании транслятора.

Comment: Дружище, твой код очень краток, доступен и понятен, поначалу хотел тебе ответ поставить, только ограничение мешало - но парень выше постарался и расписал, так что не в обиду, ему репа больше нужна, но оба ответа очень годные, спасибо.

Comment: @Silento - "Понимаем." Tоварищ Сухов "Белое солнце пустыни" :)

Comment: стрелочная функция не везде подойдет, в простых примерах да, но при работе с прототипами могут появиться сложности. я вместо ```var``` использую```let```. Это ведь тоже новый стандарт) просто достаточно вначале всего скрипта поставить 'use strict'и все будет ок)'