# Объявление функции через переменную против function

Tags: javascript

Я не знаю как правильно это описать в заголовке, но хочу понять вот что..
Зачем объявлять функцию так:

```js
const funcName = () => {};
```

... или так:

```js
const funcName = function () {};
```

... а не так:

```js
function funcName() {};
```

Если мы находимся в глобальной области.
Я понимаю, что первые две функции можно вызвать лишь после их нахождения в коде, а последнюю можно  вызвать до ее нахождения в коде.
Но каков смысл их объявления в начале? Разве это удобно, ведь придется их вечно пролистывать, чтобы перейти к "основному" коду.

Comment: Первые два случая - это _функциональные выражения_, третий - статическое объявление функции. О функциональных выражениях вроде была статья на MDN. И кстати, при хорошем оформлении, основной код обычно именно в начале модуля (не в конце). Чтобы в начале модуля множество объявлений не мешалось, используют организацию кода (не только статические функции, но и импорты - последние особенно помогают с сахарным описанием объектных типов через `class`, который не поднимается, в смысле hoisting'а).

Comment: Когда это подключается как модуль - окей, но если писать функции прямо в основном файле, какая от этого польза?

Comment: Польза обычно в той же самой организации кода, т.е. в контексте хорошей практики объявления переменных (как можно ближе к месту, где предполагается их использование). Плюс, зачастую ФВ применяются именно в локальном лексическом окружении, т.е. внутри функции (не в "корне" модуля). _//переписал коммент из-за опечатки_

Comment: Связанный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/660202/288409

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для кого-то это дело вкуса. А для кого-то важны такие особенности:

1. Hoisting может быть нежелательным, нужно более строгое и предсказуемое поведение кода.
2. Переменную `const` нельзя переопределить, а переменную `function` можно (а в нестрогом режиме можно ещё и объявить несколько раз), и это может привести к путанице:

```js
function funcName() { 42; }
console.log(funcName.toString()); // function funcName() { 0; }
function funcName() { 0; }
console.log(funcName.toString()); // function funcName() { 0; }
funcName = 42;
console.log(funcName); // 42
```

3. Переменная с `function` (как и переменная `var`) в глобальной области видимости создаёт свойство в объекте `window`, засоряя глобальную область видимости, а переменная `const` — нет.

```js
const func1 = function () {};
function func2() {}

console.log(window.func1); // undefined
console.log(window.func2); // function func2() {}
```

Comment: Это все "плюсы"?

Comment: Для кого как) По-моему, это серая зона. Если вы программируете для себя, решайте, как вам удобнее и безопаснее. Если в команде, посоветуйтесь, что более приемлемо для всех, если это ещё не определено правилами линтера, например.

Comment: Понял, спасибо.

Comment: #3 неверен: статическое объявление функции, она далеко не всегда попадает в свойства глобального объекта. При статическом объявлении внутри другой функции, этого не произойдет (т.е. дело вообще не в различии ФВ/функция, а в скоупе, и связано с механикой действия hoisting'а... так, в частности, ФВ присвоенные var-переменной, поднимаются аналогично статическому объявлению функции).

Comment: @yar85 Да, в модулях тоже такого не будет. Я имел в виду глобальную область, как и автор в вопросе. Сейчас уточню)

Comment: Можно еще добавить тот плюс, что ФВ могут быть анонимными и использоваться "на месте", в частности как коллбэк или IIFE - создавая объект функции без добавления "лишней" именованной сущности в окружение (когда переиспользование объявляемой функции не требуется). Тогда как статические объявления функции, всегда именованные.